# Can I input strings into "features" for DecisionTreeClassifiers for scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am following the Google Dev Machine Learning Recipe. I am trying to use this ML algorithm to help me solve a problem faced at work. We often get a variety of different formats for dates when performing ETL, and would like to be able to identify certain rows as dates.

The current solution that works is Regex, I would like to use ML to train the computer to identify dates as well.

The code I am referring to from Google Dev is this (Object Recognition):

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import tree
#Featuers:  0 = "bumpy" 1 = "smooth"
#Labels:    0 = apple 1 = orange
features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]]
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1]

# We will be using a Decision Tree in this instance
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

#fit = This is the training algorithm, this helps identify patterns as 
to what attributes are associated with apples etc

clf = clf.fit(features, labels)

print(clf.predict([[160, 0]])) #This outputs 1, so it believes it is an orange.
```

I want to load an entire column of different date types (12/12/12, Dec-12-12, etc) and different strings (12 12 12, user/Documents/Python etc).

The next column is going to be of type string (converted into 0 and 1 in code as variable "labels"): 1 = if the string is a date, 0 = if the string is just a string.

Hopefully I am on the right track of thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not accept. You have to do your feature engineering by converting them to number format.

For example,

1)For strings in categorical columns/features - do one-hot encoding

2)For dates - convert them to days from current_date

Comment: What exactly do you mean by converting them from current_date? I understand the one-hot encoding, and I will be sure to do that when classifying them either as a string or a date, but I am confused on what you mean by converting them to days from current_date.

Comment: @rmahesh He's saying that you need to extract features from the date, like date, month, day of week, year, etc which you can then be able to use in the algorithm. Search more about how to do it. [See this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/machine-learning-features-engineering-from-date-time-data) for a start.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar  Thank you for the link, will start with the link you provided.